# How to prevent Edits to Multi-Item form but allow edits to text box on the same form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to disable edits to the form repeating lines but allow edits to the search argument. When I set the form's allow edit to false, edit is disabled from the entire form. I only want editing to be allowed to the criteria.

I have tried setting the form's AllowEdit property to false, and then manually set the specific control's Enabled property to true, but this did not work.

Maybe I could have started with a split form instead!

I could write code to prevent update, add and delete from events but this would be silly unless there is no other way.

I want to be able to perform the functionality from VBA because, it depends on the user privileges.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Let the form to allow edits and lock individual controls. You can set the form's recordset to snapshot as well.

Comment: @KostasK., I don't know how to address every row in the  detail section to protect it. I can only get access to current row using me.FldName.

Comment: You can do this at design mode - select the control(s) in detail pane you need to lock and set lock to True. Even in VBA if you lock one control e.g. ContactPhone, all ContactPhone controls (ie in the same column) will be locked. On the contrary if you need specific rows to be locked, you need to lock on Enter and unlock on Exit.

Comment: It's easier to set the form's recordset to snapshot in the properties window though if you want to be read-only.

Comment: @KostasK., you are the one! It works. I will be happy to mark your comments as an answer if you create one. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out. :)